# Different Images Based On A Range Of Score

Tags: html, image

I recently was following a youtube tutorial on creating a whack-a-mole type game: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=toNFfAaWghU.

I followed the code just fine till the end and now I'm wondering if it is possible to set up a system that could detect the score of the user when the time runs out and show different pictures (1-5 star ratings) based a range of scores.

**Here is the code:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Whack-A-Bear!</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://www.cssfontstack.com/Gill-Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<audio autoplay>
  <source src="Outrun - Original Arcade Music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

  <h1>Whack-A-Bear! <span class="score">0</span></h1>
    <center><h2>But Not A Hare!!</h2></center>

  <div id="timer">
  <h2>Timer</h2>
  <p id="TimerDisplay">00:15</p>
  </div>

  <center><button onClick="startGame()">Click Here To Start!</button></center>
  <div class="game">

  <div class="hole hole1">
      <div class="mole"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hole hole2">
      <div class="mole"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hole hole3">
      <div class="mole"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hole hole4">
      <div class="mole"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hole hole5">
      <div class="mole"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hole hole6">
      <div class="mole"></div>
    </div>  
  </div>

<script>

/*https://medium.freecodecamp.org/javascripts-var-let-and-const-variables-explained-with-a-story-2038e3c6b2f9 */

  const holes = document.querySelectorAll('.hole');
  const scoreBoard = document.querySelector('.score');
  const moles = document.querySelectorAll('.mole');

  /*The querySelector() method only returns the first element that matches the specified CSS selectors. 
  To return all the matches, use the querySelectorAll() method instead.*/

  let lastHole;
  let timeUp = false;
  let score = 0;

  //set random timing for the moles to pop up
  function randomTime(min, max) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
  }

//set random holes for the moles to pop up from the list of our six holes
  function randomHole(holes) {
    const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * holes.length);
    const hole = holes[idx];
    // if by chance, we keep getting the same one as the last one, run the function again 
    if (hole === lastHole) {
    //shows that it was about to show you the same hole but didn't so ran the function again
      console.log('Ah nah thats the same one bud');
      return randomHole(holes);
    }
    lastHole = hole;
    return hole;
  }
  function peep() {
  var imgs = ["yes.png", "Final Hare.png"];
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgs.length);
  var raccoon = document.getElementById('raccoon.png');

  // these random times refer to how long the mole will stay popped up
    const time = randomTime(200, 1000);
    const hole = randomHole(holes);
    //shows the random home in a random amount of time
    console.log(time, hole);
    var mole = hole.querySelector(".mole");
  mole.style.background = "url('" + imgs[i] + "') bottom center no-repeat";
  mole.style.backgroundSize = "60%";
    //triggers the CSS to get the mole to come up
    hole.classList.add('up');
    //makes the mole go away after it has come up => means after the time's up, remove the mole
    setTimeout(() => {
      hole.classList.remove('up');
      //if the time is not up, then run peep () again
      if (!timeUp) peep();
    }, time);
  }
  function startGame() {
    scoreBoard.textContent = 0;
    timeUp = false;
    score = 0;
    peep();
    //a Timeout function will run when time up is true at 10 seconds
    setTimeout(() => timeUp = true, 15000)


    var sec = 15;
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById('TimerDisplay').innerHTML='00:'+sec;
    sec--;
    if (sec < 0) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    }

    }, 1000);



  }  
  function bonk(e) {
  //function bonk will take in an event which will be us clicking each of the moles
    //you can simulate a click in JS but here we don't want that to be possible
    if(!e.isTrusted) return; // cheater! To prevent a fake click if the event is not trusted, not clicked with mouse
    score++;
    this.parentNode.classList.remove('up');
    scoreBoard.textContent = score;
  }
  moles.forEach(mole => mole.addEventListener('click', bonk));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a switch statement for the image on the end screen such as

```
switch(true){
    case score > firstStarRatingValue:
        document.getElementById("END IMAGE ID").style.backgroundImage = "url(\"IMAGE1.png\")";
        break;
    case score > secondStarRatingValue:
        document.getElementById("END IMAGE ID").style.backgroundImage = "url(\"IMAGE2.png\")";
        break;
    case score > thirdStarRatingValue:
        document.getElementById("END IMAGE ID").style.backgroundImage = "url(\"IMAGE3.png\")";
        break;
    case score > fourthStarRatingValue:
        document.getElementById("END IMAGE ID").style.backgroundImage = "url(\"IMAGE4.png\")";
        break;
    default:
        //because you probably don't want an upper limit on score 
        document.getElementById("END IMAGE ID").style.backgroundImage = "IMAGE5.png";
}
```

And you would call that at the end

and because I didn't know the id for the end, i just put `END IMAGE ID` so that is something you'll have to change.

In the future, please cut your code down to a minimal example. It makes things easier to read for the ones trying to help.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, I am unclear what I should replace the "END IMAGE ID" with. Where should I have to put the given code if I wanted it to be called when the timer runs out (on the same screen as the game).

Comment: Ok so when your game finishes you need to have an end screen that takes the place of your game screen so I would actually have game be hidden when the timer ends and another div take its place maybe by giving them the same class so they show up similarly. could you put your code into a snippet and include the css so its easier to see what you're working with?

Comment: What? Why would you do that?

Comment: function startGame() {
    scoreBoard.textContent = 0;
    timeUp = false;
    score = 0;
    peep();
    //a Timeout function will run when time up is true at 10 seconds
    setTimeout(() => timeUp = true, 15000)
    
    if timeUp = true; { window.open("End Screen.html")}
    
    
    
    
    var sec = 15;
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById('TimerDisplay').innerHTML='00:'+sec;
    sec--;
    if (sec < 0) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    }
    
    }, 1000);
    
    
  }

Comment: Do you have a discord? I think it'd be best place to sort this out cause the comments aren't really for this sort of stuff

Comment: ItsKonik is my discord.

Comment: Nvm add me @matt-the-marxist#3832